# how to remove one label from dataframe in r

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am working on the dataset bookdata.tsv.gz for my first assignment.Of all the book labels, I need to exclude title "wild animus" from my analysis.How can I do that ? I am just a beginner so a little explanation with the code chunk will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Examine the difference between `mtcars` and `mtcars[-(rownames(mtcars) == "Valiant"),]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
subset(dataFrame, select = -c(Wild.animus))
dataFrame[, -grep('Wild', colnames(dataFrame))]
dataFrame[, -grep('animus', colnames(dataFrame))]
dataFrame[, -grep('Wild animus', colnames(dataFrame))]
```

Comment: I tried it..
subset(basket_rules1, select = -c(Wild.animus))
basket_rules1[, -grep('Wild', colnames(basket_rules1))]
basket_rules1[, -grep('animus', colnames(basket_rules1))]
basket_rules1[, -grep('Wild animus', colnames(basket_rules1))]

Comment: It gives an error
Error in basket_rules1[, -grep("Wild animus", colnames(basket_rules1))] : 
  incorrect dimension (j not possible)